# Number in Sequence that a pair falls in

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to find what number in the sequence a pair falls in.  I am trying to write a procedure that verifies that f(1, n) = 2n - 2 and f(m+1, n+1) = 2f(m, n).  It works when I call (number 99, 100), but it doesn't work when I call (number 100, 100).  Why doesn't it work?  What is the sequence number for (100, 100)?

Here is my procedure:

```
(define (number m n)
   (if (= m 1)
       (- (* 2 n) 2)
       (* 2 (number (- m 1) (- n 1)))))
```

Comment: You should explain better what do you mean with "what number in the sequence a pair falls". What sequence? where did the formula come from?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you believe the procedure "doesn't work"? the function, as defined, is correctly implementing the desired formula - and will always lead to this base case when both `m` and `n` are equal:

```
(- (* 2 1) 2) ; if m equals 1 then n equals 1
```

The above will return `0` of course, and all the multiplications in the recursion will cancel, because you'll be multiplying by zero over and over again:

```
(* 2 (* 2 ... (* 2 0)))
=> 0
```

So the problem is not in the procedure itself, but in the formula it's implementing. Make sure it's correct.